# Uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression jQuery

Tags: jquery, syntax, expression

I am having a few problems with jQuery 1.6, I am trying to select this object `$('#' + id)` where id looks like `skill|3345015|7868`, but console always give me a :

> Error : uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   |3345015|7868

Thanks for your help

Comment: I wish this question were more clear, in whether id was actually "skill|123...etc.", or whether that was just the selector, and id ~may~ be "skill or "123" or etc..  Read both answers for a full understanding.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try -

```
$("div[id='skill|3345015|7868']")
```

You'll have to replace 'div' with whatever element you're searching for. Or, to search all elements -

```
$("*[id='skill|3345015|7868']")
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/dV7xM/

Answer (score 14):

According to w3.org

> **ID** and **NAME** tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may
>   be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

So basically you have an invalid ID and that should be the reason for the parse error

Comment: so basically jQuery is stuck at HTML 4, since HTML 5 allows any character in an id :(